# virtualbox guest additions : CPU stuck for 22 seconds

Tags: virtualbox

On debian under virtualbox, i tried to install virtualbox guest additions, but it's give me this error after a long time :

```
CPU stuck for 22 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this problem :

- You have shut down your virtual debian
- **Put Only 1 or 2 processor** in the setting of the virtual machine
- Start your virtual machine
- Install virtualbox guest additions